# How to load local image using Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using android's [photo-picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) and then dumping the path into a DB. That all works, but when I try to load the image from RoomDB the image does not load.

I've tried using `Image` and `AsyncImage`, but no luck. I've also converted the string to `.toUri()`

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter(data = File("content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000020"))
Image( painter = painter, contentDescription = null)


AsyncImage(model = "content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000020",
 contentDescription = "Image from photo picker",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp, 100.dp)
)
```

Comment: When you get the `Uri` initially, you may need to [take steps to ensure that you can use it in future process invocations](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). I have not tried this with the new media `Intent` actions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you load the image you must ensure that you have the permission to read the image. Try this code before you load the image

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val uri = Uri.parse("content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000020")
context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```